# Is there a standard Haskell function like iterate that stops for Nothing?

Tags: haskell, standard-library, haskell-platform

I am wondering if there is a standard function that iterates a function that returns a (Maybe value) over an initial value, collecting the values in a list, but ending the list when it gets to Nothing.  This function can be implemented for example like so:

```
iterateMaybe f a = a : iterMaybe (f a) where
  iterMaybe Nothing = []
  iterMaybe (Just a) = a : iterMaybe (f a)
```

or slightly differently like so:

```
iterateMaybe' f Nothing = []
iterateMaybe' f (Just a) = a : iterateMaybe' f (f a)
```

None of [the functions that Hoogle finds](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a%20-%3E%20%28Maybe%20a%29%29%20-%3E%20a%20-%3E%20[a]) match.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a special case of [`unfoldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr).

```
iterateMaybe f = unfoldr (fmap (\s -> (s,s)) . f)
```

The difference is list returned by `unfoldr` won't include the initial element.

Comment: And of course, you can do `iterateMaybe f x = x : helper f x` where `helper` has the definition of `iterateMaybe` given in the answer. That gives you the list starting at the initial element.